# submitting input field and file to server.(Not working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, file-upload, react-router

what is wrong with the below code? I can not use `functional component` because its legacy application. so I am using `class`.
when I am clicking on `upload` button `console.log` is printing undefined. nothing is happening at `server` end.

Could you please check `handleSubmit` method?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class FileUpload extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedFile: '',
      countryCode: '',
      responseArray: [],
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.value,
      responseArray: [],
    });
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    this.setState({
      countryCode: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    if (!this.state.selectedFile) {
      alert('Please select The file');
      return false;
    }
    if (!this.state.countryCode) {
      alert('Please select The Country Code');
      return false;
    }
    const data = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.selectedFile.length; i++) {
      data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile[i]);
    }
    data.append('countryCode', this.state.countryCode);
    console.log(data.countryCode);

    let url = process.env.API_URL;

    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/file_upload', data, {}).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(data);
        // this.setState({ responseArray: res.data });
        // this.resetFile();
      },
      (error) => {
        alert(error);
      }
    );
  }

  resetFile() {
    document.getElementsByName('file')[0].value = null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <h1>Translation File Upload</h1>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="form-group col-md-8">
                <label>Please enter the country code</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={this.state.countryCode}
                  onChange={this.handleInput}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="form-group col-md-8">
                <label>Select File :</label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  className="form-control"
                  multiple
                  name="file"
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                  required
                />
                <hr />
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="col-md-6">
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Upload </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FileUpload;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `handleInputChange` to

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
      responseArray: [],
    });
  }
```

Relevant [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#accessing_selected_files_on_a_change_event).

Comment: can yu please also check whether it is sending proper payload to server. because when I am sending from postman it is working properly. from this componenet 500 error is coming. also i think it is not validatiing prper input. thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: also there is one file, not multiple. please suggest changes. I am very new to react. due to urgency in project working on it.

Comment: Well, `input.files` contains the `FileList` and to get the individual files you can use array syntax like `input.files[0]`